# Using Interrupts for User input from Console I/O in Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly

### What is The Interrupt for User input and output in Console Window?

Hello I'm trying to learn Assembly Language, I know that in MS-DOS Operating System, the `.COM` programs were Supported, and were loaded into memory at `100h`, isn't it? And the first `1k` bytes were the IVT or Interrupt vector table, it is a list of interrupts, isn't it?? So in MS-DOS if we want to Ask an input from the user we first Move `01` to `AH` register like `MOV ah, 01` and call the Interrupt `INT 21h`, I don't know if this is gonna work on DOS or not, I never tried the DOS virtual machine or something Similar Applications, i don't want the DOS program I just want a Console Window for Asking a user for Input...

I have just stepped into Assembly programming and found no Complete tutorials on Windows, Or not just One which Shows the use of Interrupts, Everywhere MASM is used with `windows.inc` libs, and the `C standard libs`, i don't wanna waste my time learning them, As after learning Assembly programming i Want to learn Writing Booting Programs, Which doesn't Sticks to one Operating system, And the reason i want to use Interrupts is just for learning purpose, Meaning this is just to learn Assembly language, Currently i know very less instructions like `MOV` `ADD` `SUB` `INC` `INT` & `DEC` And know nothing or very less about Registers, So with these limited Capability i cannot write Boot Programs, and for this reason im trying to learn or Practice assembly on Windows but with interrupts, and thus does not want to use those Predefined libraries in my Applications, and want to Only use Interrupts from IVTs and shift to BIOS interrupts, for Boot Programs.

I heard on a forum that Microsoft hides its Windows IVTs from the public as they want their APIs to become popular, Is this true? Thus this means there is no way i can use interrupts to handle I/O in Windows?? because there is no such Documentary on it, if No Kindly Post it with An Example for NASM, and Please Refer to any Online/Offline guide, and my last request please Tell me how can i Convert MASM written souce code for NASM, i mean what is the difference between them, In Short, i have Two requests and One Question as follows:

### 1. Q1: What is the Interrupt for Console I/O in Windows?

### 2. R1: Please share any Good tutorials on Assembly for windows Especially on using Interrupts just like [TutorialsPoint](http://tutorialspoint.com) but Its for Linux and I want for Windows.

And the Last One...

### 3. R2: How is MASM's input file source code different from NASM one?? I mean How much and where can i find difference writing source code for them, As many tutorials said that Many MASM programs wont run in NASM...

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And the first 1k bytes were the IVT or Interrupt vector table ...

Modern CPUs have two (in the case of 64-bit CPUs even three) operating modes: The "real mode" and the "protected mode".

When the CPU starts up and in MS-DOS the CPU runs in "real mode". When Windows is running the CPU runs in "protected mode". In this mode the interrupt system works completely different than in "real mode".

It is not possible to access the IVT directly and it is not possible to access memory belonging to a task from another task.

> What is the Interrupt for Console I/O in Windows?

Windows NT, 32-bit, used interrupt 1Eh. However other Windows versions (Windows 9x for example) used another method of entering the operating system.

As far as I know 64-bit versions of Windows also do not use interrupts.

No Windows program (with exception of the old 16-bit Windows programs) is using interrupts directly.

> hides its Windows IVTs from the public as they want their APIs to become popular, Is this true?

They hide the interrupt numbers because they are only available in some Windows versions.

The only possibility to write a program that works on all Windows versions currently in use is to use the Windows APIs.

> i don't wanna waste my time learning them

In this case don't waste your time writing Assembler programs for Windows! Doing so only makes sense if you are interested in compiler development.

Use some virtual machine tool (Bochs, VMware, ...) and start writing "booting programs" NOW or use an MS-DOS emulator and write Assembler programs for MS-DOS.

The only use of Assembler programs for Windows is that the 32-bit assembler is a bit easier to learn than the 16-bit assembler (which is required for MS-DOS and "booting programs") so writing Assembler programs for Windows may be good for learning purposes...

Comment: And should i Directly start Learn writing boot programs without even learning to write for a Platform? I thought Learning through Interrupts in Windows, will be easier than writing Boot programs, i will practise Assembly language there, And then to Go on writing Boot Programs, Ok this means i have to look for Tutorials on writing Boot programs?? if you know some Good and easy(for as a beginer) Tutorials please share it, And thanks for your Answer!!...